# spring boot rabbitmq RabbitTemplate error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am taking the error that "Could not autowire. No beans of 'RabbitTemplate' type found". I normally try to autowired RabbitTemplate to my producer class but it gives like that error.

i tried to solve creating bean in configuration file. but it did not work.

```
package com.example.rabbitmqexample.producer;

import com.example.rabbitmqexample.model.Notification;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class NotificationProducer {

    @Value("${sr.rabbit.routing.name}")
    private String routingName;

    @Value("${sr.rabbit.exchange.name}")
    private String exchangeName;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void sendToQueue(Notification notification){
        System.out.println("Notification Sent ID: "+notification.getNotificationId());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName,routingName,notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, an answer provided, if it suits you requirement please consider to upvote and accept it, otherwise feel free to leave comment ti improve community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exception suggest there is no instance of `RabbitTemplate` with in [IOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) container, thus it can not be inject on other bean declarations like 'NotificationProducer' class.

You said

> i tried to solve creating bean in configuration file. but it did not work.

**Solution**

proper bean declaration for [RabbitTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html), with respecting constructor and dependent bean binding they are many [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605592/15758781) to do that. one practice to proper bean declaration with [ConnectionFactory](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/4.0.2/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html) as a dependent bean for `RabbitTemplate` is as follow.

```html
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    ...

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        //adding perhaps some extra confoguration to template like message convertor. etc.
        ...
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

Always check the [version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/) docs depending the artifact version you are using for compatibility.